# error al intalar paquetes en manjaro

Tags: linux, manjaro

Al intentar instalar algun programa la consola me arroja esto:

```
error: no se pudo abrir el archivo /var/cache/pacman/pkg/archlinux-keyring-20200820-1-any.pkg.tar.zst: Unrecognized archive format
error: no se pudo abrir el archivo /var/cache/pacman/pkg/manjaro-keyring-20200603-1-any.pkg.tar.zst: Unrecognized archive format
error: no se pudo abrir el archivo /var/cache/pacman/pkg/manjaro-system-20200906-1-any.pkg.tar.zst: Unrecognized archive format
error: no se pudo realizar la operación (no se pudo abrir el archivo del paquete)
```

Ocurrieron errores, por lo que no se actualizaron los paquetes.

La verdad ya no se que puede ser.